# Empty column with float datatype returns 1 value

Tags: mysql

I would like to ask something, please be good to me.

This is one of my column fields with its datatype.

column_name: amount_paid
datatype: float(13,2)

When I count this column, it returns value 1 even if there's no existing value or inserted on it.

Before Query: [image]
After Query: [image]

Query used: SELECT COUNT(amount_paid), COUNT(amount_unpaid) from transactions

I want to achieved a Zero(0) value because of my own reason.

Please be good to me, thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by 'if there's no existing value or inserted on it' mean no records in this table? please put the sql that you have tried

Comment: The default value is 0.00 and when I count the column field it resulted a 1 value. I need the value to be 0. I will edit my post with my query used.

Comment: amount_paid and amount_unpaid columns are float in datatype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need sum not count.

count is use to count rows [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html)

sum is use to accumulate the value of the field [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum), you might need to use a group by clause

```
SELECT SUM(amount_paid), SUM(amount_unpaid) from transactions
```

Comment: Hello! I just read it now, I will try it and make a feedback later on. Thanks for giving my post some time. Have a good day!

Answer (score -1):

Has to be null to count like Cero you can do something like this

```
    UPDATE table SET column = NULL WHERE test = "example";
```